# How to Compile GPX Read Support into a C# Project (Using OGR/GPX Driver)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gpx, ogr, expat-parser

When I throw the path to a GPX file to OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.Open(), I get null back instead of a populated DataSource. In my situation, I believe this is happening because I'm not building my OGR/GPX driver with read support (that's what my log file says, at least):

[ERROR] :: GDAL [code=6 msg=OGR/GPX driver has not been built with read support. Expat library required]

I've got the libexpat.dll I believe it wants in my GDAL directory. My question now is, how do I build OGR with it so that I can start getting an actual DataSource from that Ogr.Open(path_to_gpx_file) call? I've tried adding it as a reference to my project, but to no avail (because it's an unmanaged DLL I believe, the internet tells me that's a no-no).